# Access directive attribute value in the jasmine test

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, tdd, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I have a example AngularJS directive like this `<div some-dir="5" />`

How would I access this directive attribute value of `5` inside my test?

```
describe("some-dir", function() {
    var element, scope;
    beforeEach(module('app'));
    beforeEach(inject(function($rootScope, $compile) {

        scope = $rootScope;
        element = angular.element('<div><div id="el1" some-dir="5" /></div>');
        $compile(element)(scope);
        scope.$digest();

    }));

    it('should be able to get the attribute value', function(){

       // get the attr value of some-dir


    });

});
```

Comment: Please share your jasmine test. What are you trying to test?\

Comment: I want to test that my directive can access my attribute correctly. ie. the directive is using this value - hence different val of the attribute different result.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can check scope values of element using its *isolateScope* method. But this won't work when you pass a value right next to directive attribute, as those values are not copied into isolated scope.

In that case, it's possible to get and test that value using *element.attributes* method.

First compile your directive html:

```
var element;

beforeEach(inject(function (_$compile_, _$rootScope_) {
    var $compile = _$compile_,
        $scope = _$rootScope_;

    element = $compile('<div my-directive="4" some-value="5"></div>')($scope);
    $scope.$digest();
}));
```

Then you can expect **element**'s isolateScope to return an object with *someValue* property.

```
it('should expect some-value as 5', function () {
    inject(function ($injector) {
        // check attribute values using isolateScope
        expect(element.isolateScope().someValue).toEqual(5);

        // check the value right after directive attribute
        expect(element.attr('my-directive')).toEqual('4');
    });
});
```

Here is an example [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/97XrTTrNbsQKln49kDGw?p=preview).

Comment: i don't think it will. why don't you pass your values with separated attributes? You can use element directive anyway: <my-directive some-value="5"></my-directive>

Comment: Yes, could do that as well. But.. is this even possible as per my original question?

Comment: Thanks, sorry to be pain, this does work perfectly if you are not nesting divs, will `element.find('selector').attr('my-directive')` work here?

Comment: Shouldn't my-directive always be the root element here? Anyway, i guess you have a different use case. That statement should work too, but remember that you can only use tag selector with jqLite. If you need a more complex selector, you'll need include jQuery.

Comment: Yes this is very edge case, most probably not very useful in real world. Anyway, thanks for your time.